# KeyPressFcn in Matlabs App Designer

Tags: matlab, keypress, keystroke

Hey there great ppl out there!

I have a rather simple problem but no idea how to solve it. 2h Google search didn´t help.

I´m getting hands on Matlab´s App Designer.

To keep it simple: I have a button and a numerical field. Every time I click the button - a callback is called increasing the value of the numerical field by 1.

How can I implement a KeyPress event?!? I.e. When I press the '+' Key on my keyboard I would like to trigger the callback fuction of the button (or if not possible any other function).

I´m pretty sure the developers of App Designer must have thought about this - but I´m simply to untalented to find the right documentation. I think in GUIDE there´s something called 'keypressfcn' - so I basically need an equivalent for the App Designer.

Please help :)

[Increasing the Number field by 1 when hitting the button or pressing the '+' key on my keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzB2L.png)

Comment: As of R2017b, I don't believe this callback is implemented yet for `UIFigure` or `UIAxes`. You'll have to use legacy components for this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I moved back to GUIDE. Appdesigner seems to be a nice thing to have in future. But due to the lack of features and its quite buggy environment - it will probably take some further development until Appdesigner is functionally useable.

Answer (score 1):

A KeyPressFcn has been added as of Matlab R2019a. In appdesigner click the Callback button, select your figure, then choose the callback 'KeyPress'. I got it to work. More info here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figureappd-properties.html